# Hive - compare two string columns

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a free style text in column A (sourcestring) of table A. I am trying to parse column A with every value in Column B (substring) of table B. To see if any of the substring in column b is present in column A. if the substring is present then i want corresponding column C (category)as the result

I was able to achieve it for a smaller data set through case statements like below but I have the list of substring and category increasing. How do i go about this.

```
SELECT A.sourcestring, A.primarykey, B.substring, B.category, 
       CASE
          WHEN lower(sourcestring) IS NULL THEN NULL
          WHEN lower(sourcestring) RLIKE '%blister|burn|fire|grill|hot|lighter|oven|scald|scorch|stove|torch|welder%'
          THEN 'burn '
          ELSE 'other' 
        END
```

Table A

```
sourcestring         
"i am here"    
"he is here"
```

Table B

```
substring | category
"here"    | "present"  
"not"     | "not present"
"mad"     | "not related"
```

I want the resulting table to be

Table c

```
sourcestring    resultcategory     
"i am here"     "present"         
"he is here"    "present"
```